# If $\sum a_n$ is convergent but not absolutely, then $\sum a_n^+$ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Let $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|= \infty$ and $\sum_{n=1}^m a_n \to a$, as $m \to \infty$. Let $a_n^+=\max\{a_n,0\}.$ Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^+= \infty$.

Approach:

We know, in case of real numbers, $\max\{a,b\}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(a+b+|a-b|)$. Hence, $a_n^+=\max\{a_n,0\}=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(a_n+|a_n|)$. Therefore, the sum becomes,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^+=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle\frac{1}{2}(a_n+|a_n|)=\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|=\infty$

As far as I can remember, I asked this question here earlier (but I have forgotten entirely how I tackled it; I don't want to steal ideas from the past). But this time, I am asking this again here in order to get this verified (not much confident with my procedure).

Thank you!

Comment: This is perfectly fine.

Comment: @TheoBendit :D Thank you for the response .

Comment: While I agree with Theo, just make sure you can justify why you can split apart the sum (you go from $\sum(a_n+|a_n|)$ to $\sum a_n +\sum|a_n|$).

Comment: Because $\sum (p_n + q_n) =\sum p_n + \sum q_n$. (Due to the associative property of the additive group of reals) and in this case, the ordering of the terms does not change. Anything else?

Comment: correct me if I am mistaken

Comment: The ordering does change, albeit only subtly (think of it like $\sum\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$... this clearly does not equal $\sum1/n-\sum1/(n+1)$). You can justify splitting apart the sum because the sum of one of the terms is summable (if $\sum a_n+b_n$ converges and $\sum a_n$ converges, it can be shown that $\sum(a_n+b_n)-\sum a_n=\sum b_n$ must also converge. This is slightly different from what you have, but I think it can be adapted.)

Comment: what should be the clarification then?

Comment: I just edited my comment; you may need to refresh to see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93837/discussion-between-subhasis-biswas-and-clayton).